# LogStash::ConfigurationError: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded

Tags: elasticsearch

When I use the `logstash_input_jdbc` plugin sync MySQL and my local elastic search,

**The below errors appear**, But I search for a long time, but I have no resolve method until now.

> ./logstash -f ./logstash_jdbc_test/jdbc.conf 
>       Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>#,
>   :backtrace=>["/usr/local/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.0.2/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:156:in
>   `prepare_jdbc_connection'",
>   "/usr/local/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:167:in`
>   register'",
>   "/usr/local/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:330:in
>   `start_inputs'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'",
>   "/usr/local/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:329:in
>   `start_inputs'",
>   "/usr/local/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:180:in`
>   start_workers'",
>   "/usr/local/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in
>   `run'",
>   "/usr/local/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.2-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:465:in`
>   start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday, I find the reason.
The reason is:
In my install path /elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.2.0/lib, the size of  mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar is zero.
So I download the new mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar, and copy to the path of  /elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.2.0/lib. 
And then, my problem resolved.

Now I can sync date between mysql and elaticsearch quickly.

Comment: Mine was 0 too still don't know why