# logstash: not able to connect mysql with logstash?

Tags: mysql, logstash

I am trying to make connection with MySQL using logstash and write into elastic search below in my code in conf file

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.24:3306/test"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "uname"
        jdbc_password => "pass"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT * FROM report_table"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    action => "index"
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "mysqlsample"
    document_type => "record"
    }
}
```

on running the above getting the below error :

> Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included
>   the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?   Exception:
>   LogStash::ConfigurationError   Stack:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:162:in
>   `open_jdbc_connection'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:220:in`
>   execute_statement'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:264:in
>   `execute_query'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:250:in`
>   run'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:514:in
>   `inputworker'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:507:in`
>   block in start_input'

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368567/logstashconfigurationerror-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-not-loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's an issue with `jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/6.2.4/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar"`.

Are you sure it's a valid path? Is that the correct connector? Maybe try to use the one that the documentation mentions: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html),

The class to use is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. Have you tried it ?